# Driver for USB debugging on an ASUS Memo Pad FHD 10 (ME302KL) on Windows 7

Tags: android, driver, tablet, usb-debugging

I need to debug some Android apps on a real device. I have an ASUS Memo Pad 10 and a desktop with Windows 7.

I tried following the instructions on the Android Developer site and turned on the USB-Debug option on the tablet, but my desktop can't find any relevant driver in the Android SDK directories, and using "adb devices" gives me an empty list.

Is there a way to get my desktop to recognize this tablet?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Download http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePAD/ME173X/ASUS_Android_USB_drivers_for_Windows.zip.
2. Extract files.
3. Right click on Computer and select "Manage".
4. Click Device Manager.
5. Right click on "ME302KL" and choose "Update Driver Software..." and do a manual install.

Comment: I downloaded the drivers for my model, but when I choose the folder, Windows doesn't find drivers :s